# PhpStorm and Xdebug not working in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, xdebug

I am using php 8.1, PhpStorm version 2021.2.3. Xdebug 3
When I create a single PHP file and run it in the built-in web server I can debug correctly opening it from the browser with the Debug extension enabled.  However, when I try to do the same from the Laravel project nothing happens.

This is my Xdebug config:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=trigger
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.discover_client_host=1
```

php -v

```
PHP 8.1.0 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2021 01:33:49) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.0, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.1.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

If I try for example creating a breakpoint in my controller and running my project on the browser with the Xdebug extension enabled nothing happens.
Also, if I create a breakpoint in a model and try to do `php artisan tinker` and trigger it nothing happens either.

I am wondering what could I be missing.

[image]

Comment: 1) Show your actual live config -- a full screenshot of `xdebug_info()` output; 2) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and then share the log -- it will show what Xdebug tries to do. 3) Will it make any difference if you try with `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` instead? 4) Why do you need `xdebug.discover_client_host=1`? Is that code runs on another computer/VM? If it's local, just use `xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1` (if you use `localhost` then in some cases it may resolve to IPv6 etc, so better use explicit IPv4 address)

Comment: *"Also, if I create a breakpoint in a model and try to do `php artisan tinker` and trigger it nothing happens either."* With your current setting it should do nothing. I mean -- you may not have the needed trigger (ENV variable in your case of CLI debug) for Xdebug to be active. I may suggest autostart (see #3) or placing `xdebug_break();` in the actual PHP code. In any case: the Xdebug log and settings are what you need to look at first.

Comment: Changing this did it for the browser incoming connections : xdebug.start_with_request=yes THANK YOU SO MUCH! I spent hours on this yesterday. In terms of starting a debugging session from the command line (tinker), should I have XDEBUG_CONFIG environment variable in my .env? I am getting: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(

Comment: *"Changing this did it for the browser incoming connections : xdebug.start_with_request=yes"* That just tells Xdebug to try to debug every single request automatically regardless if Xdebug cookie/parameter is in the request. I personally just remove that line completely (let it use the default value) and control debugger with Xdebug browser extension (that uses cookies) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/zero-configuration-debugging.html

Comment: *"I am getting: Xdebug: [Step Debug] Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (fallback through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-( "* Is that for CLI debug? Do you have PhpStorm listening for incoming connections at that moment (the phone handle icon)? Because that should work exactly the same in CLI and web page (esp on a local host). Must be some difference in your config if does not work if the same PHP is used (note: it's pretty common on Mac and Linux to have separate php.ini for CLI and web server; you should always check the settings in the same env)

Comment: *"In terms of starting a debugging session from the command line (tinker), should I have XDEBUG_CONFIG environment variable in my .env?"* Yes, that sort of thing. That's if you do not start the debug automatically. Or you can pass the needed params right to the PHP executable (`php -dxdebug.xxx... artisan tinker` -- this kind of things)